# I cannot copy and paste between window and ubuntu with LXDE desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, lxde

I installed VNC in the VPS with Ubuntu OS, then I installed LXDE desktop.

I remoted to the desktop of VPS via VNC, then I tried to copy between my Windows computer and the VPS, but it did not work.

I tried to search many articles in askubuntu.com and also in google.com but I cound not find the answer.

When I tried the comand `vncconfig` in the VPS, it did not work, it says:

```
-bash: vncconfig: command not found
```

I tried to remote VPS via both ways: `tightvnc` and `realvnc`, but no luck.

Can you tell me how do I fix it now?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the proplem, so I think I can answer my question for myself

THe proplem is from tightvnc

I tried to reinstall the VPS with same desktop LXDE, but then, I installed vnc4server, and now I can copy + paste between window pc and linux desktop

thanks you!